# Sony xperia sola's compat wireless drivers location

Tags: location, drivers, sony, android-wireless, sony-xperia

Where are the compat wireless drivers located at my phone? (xperia sola ICS - 6.1.1.B.1.54). When I search for .ko files, all I find are some drivers for other modules of the phone, I can't find nowhere compat wireless drivers (eg cfg80211.ko, mac80211.ko). I know they are somewhere there, as when I downloaded the source of 6.1.1.B.1.54 firmware I could find them.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The cfg80211 and mack80211 are built natiely into kernel rather than external modules.
I check kumquat's defconfig :
CONFIG_CFG80211=y
CONFIG_MAC80211=y

I think you're looking for CW1200 module.
:)